# django rest framework XML Parse - invalid token

Tags: python, xml, django, rest, django-rest-framework

My end goal is to have an external website POST data to my site using DRF. The data they send is in XML Format.

- python 2.7
- djangorestframework 3.3.2
- djangorestframework-xml 1.3.0

---

My issues is whenever the external site posts data, it returns a HTTP 400 error. But I can CURL the data fine. I am not able to find where I can see or dump the data that is in the rest framework POST. I have tried working through the parser_context dictionary being sent to `CustomXMLParse` Parse.  But I always return None, even with the successful CURL

I overrode the default XMLParser so I could retrieve an attribute. I will say I am able to successfully use the API when I CURL.

## Successful Curl

```
curl  http:/website/post/ -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<registrationreport format='summary' regid='abc123' instanceid='0'><complete>complete</complete><success>failed</success><totaltime>19</totaltime><score>0</score></registrationreport>"
```

## Views.py

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@authentication_classes((BasicAuthentication,))
@parser_classes((CustomXMLParser, ))
@permission_classes((IsAuthenticated,))
def coursePostBack(request):
      ...
      #Error from parsers.py STOPS before running anything in View
```

## Parsers.py

```
class CustomXMLParser(XMLParser):
"""
Custom XML parser.
"""
logger.debug(' coursePostBack | PARSER  HIT ')

media_type = 'text/xml'

def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None):
    logger.debug(' coursePostBack | PARSER--PARSE HIT')
    assert etree, 'XMLParser requires defusedxml to be installed'

    parser_context = parser_context or {}

    encoding = parser_context.get('encoding', settings.DEFAULT_CHARSET)
    parser = etree.DefusedXMLParser(encoding=encoding)
    try:
        ## This is where it fails! How can I SEE the data being sent in POST     ##
        tree = etree.parse(stream, parser=parser, forbid_dtd=True)
    except (etree.ParseError, ValueError) as exc:
        logger.error('XML Parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
        raise ParseError('XML parse error - %s' % six.text_type(exc))
    data = self._xml_convert(tree.getroot())
    attribs = tree.getroot().attrib
    data['regid'] = attribs['regid']
    return data
```

## Log.py

```
ERROR [training:36] XML Parse error - not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1
```

Comment: Do you just have that logger and variable media_type straight in the class? You should try putting that in the init and remove the media_type in your parse function, it will redefine the value and could be causing the problem. Also, on a slightly different topic why XML over JSON just outta curiosity?

Comment: I moved the logger to init. The media type comes from deeper in the django_rest_framework, if i remove the argument it fails because its missing.

I am forced to use XML because that's what the 3rd party is sending. I don't have control of the server POSTing the data unfortunately.

Comment: Well, The issue ended up being that the data being sent was URLencoded so it removed all the < and > symbols.  I discovered this by nesting a logger in the Django Rest Framework request.py code prior to the customer parser being called.